# Best Way to Only Search In Partial Sections of An Array

Tags: java, arrays

Please do not provide actual code, just give me items to research on how to approach this, or try and steer me in the right direction.

I currently have an assignment where I'm to read a text file into a String array, then use a product number (pid) entered by the user to configure a car by putting each option into another array.

### Here is the text file information that I've entered into a String array named anyCarConfig[]. I've included the index from the array to help illustrate this.

```
[0] - 0001 model1 10000.00

[1] - 0002 model2 20000.00
[2] - 
[3] - Options
[4] - Exterior Color
[5] - 1 Blue 3000.00
[6] - 2 Red 3000.00
[7] - 3 Green 3000.00
[8] - 4 White 3000.00
[9] - 5 Black 3000.00
[10] - 6 Yellow 3000.00
[11] - 7 Orange 3000.00
[12] - 8 Gold 3000.00
[13] - 9 Purple 3000.00
[14] - Interior Color
[15] - 1 Leather-Tan 5000.00
[16] - 2 Leather-Black 5000.00
[17] - 3 Leather-Red 5000.00
[18] - 4 Vinyl-Tan 3000.00
[19] - 5 Vinyl-Black 3000.00
[20] - 6 Vinyl-Red 3000.00
[21] - 7 Cloth-Tan 1000.00
[22] - 8 Cloth-Black 1000.00
[23] - 9 Cloth-Red 1000.00
[24] - Powertrain
[25] - 1 Automatic 7500.00
[26] - 2 Manual 5000.00
[27] - Seat
[28] - 1 Multi-Point 800.00
[29] - 2 Heated 1200.00
[30] - 3 Air 2000.00
[31] - Radio
[32] - 1 AM/FM 500.00
[33] - 2 CD 750.00
[34] - 3 MP3 850.00
[35] - 4 Sirius/XM 900.00
[36] - 5 NAV 3000.00
[37] - Tire
[38] - 1 All-Weather 500.00
[39] - 2 Sports 1100.00
[40] - 3 Premium 1500.00
[41] - Rim
[42] - 1 18 1100.00
[43] - 2 19 1200.00
[44] - 3 20 1300.00
[45] - 4 22 1400.00
[46] - 5 26 2000.00
[47] - Miscellaneous
[48] - 1 MoonRoof 3000.00
[49] - 2 SunRoof 5000.00
[50] - 3 Panaramic 8000.00
```

---

Then here is the description on how I'm to come up with the different options.

getOptions

Type: Public Static

Input: String pid - 12-digit product ID number

Return: returns a String Array of options

Description: Reads the last 8 numbers of pid and identifies the options within anyCarConfig as follows:

Index 1. Exterior Color

Index 2. Interior Color

Index 3. Powertrain

Index 4. Seat Type

Index 5. Radio Type

Index 6. Tire Size

Index 7. Rim Size

Index 8. Miscellaneous

If the number is zero then the option is None. Each option is appended to an array with the option name and type as string example: “Exterior Color: White” once all options are defined then return the array of options.

Once again don't provide me full code, because I want to learn through some trial and error. Thank you. This is my first post so I hope I did this correctly.

Here is my current thought process. Just need to some guidance.

STEP ONE: Create loop to go through pid String starting at the 5th character and store each character as I go.

STEP TWO: Start at anyCarConfig[4] and add the value from the stored character of the pid String loop to get to the correct index of anyCarConfig[].

STEP THREE: Add that anyCarConfig[] index to the getOptions() String array that I will be returning.

STEP FOUR: Start at the anyCarConfig[] that got added to getOptions() String array and loop until I find the the next entry in anyCarConfig[] that starts with a character instead of a digit.

STEP FIVE: Go through the next iteration of the pid String loop

STEP SIX: Use the index found from STEP FOUR to be the start loop through like STEP TWO.

Repeat that whole process until I've reached the end of the pid String and my getOptions() String array is created.

I know I'm missing things in there like parsing, removing characters I don't need from the anyCarConfig[] values, etc, but I just wanted to give a general idea.

Comment: You need to show us **your** attempt with your question and tell us any problems you are having with it. Please read and take to heart: [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: I did take a look at that. That's why I asked that code NOT be provided to me.

Comment: ? So if you've looked at that, then where is your best good faith attempt at a solution?

Comment: I just added my thought process on there. If I could get some guidance to at least tell me I'm going about this wrong that would help. I appreciate your quick attention to my post.

Comment: Why not first try to implement your thought process as code, test it, modify it, as you've absolutely nothing to lose? You've got your own powerful computing lab at your fingertips just waiting for your input and experimentation.

Comment: Unfortunately the only thing I have to lose is time. I have a full time job, family, and I'm taking night courses. I get about 3 hours a night, and my lunch time at work each day to do school work. I can definitely attempt to do that, but I was hoping to not waste more time than necessary since anything I do I'm still going to have some trial and error.. I'm just hoping for an answer like, "Research the binarySearch() method of the array class".

Comment: If you're serious about learning the subject then you're going to need to reserve time to do what I'm suggesting for it is in experimentation that you learn. But I'm not here to give you a lecture except to note (again) that for these types of questions on this site, a decent attempt is expected. I'm hopeful that your future questions will show this. Best of luck to you and to all your computing endeavors.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. I will try to be more concise and show more work in my questions in the future. I definitely agree that I will learn more through experimentation, but I know exactly how many hours I have between when something is assigned and when it is due. If there were no deadline the time to experiment would not be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would parse the available options first, and create several objects as categories. An object has a name (like exterior color) and a set of options. Optimally, you'd save these in a map: the key is the index of the digit which stands for the option, and the value, of course, is the option object itself.
Like:

```
Map<String, ConfigurationOption> options = new HashMap<>();
options.put(1, new ConfigurationOption("Exterior Color", "Blue", "Red", "Green", "White", "Black", "Yellow", "Orange", "Gold", "Purple");
```

And ConfigurationOption has a constructor like

```
public ConfigurationOption(String name, String ... options) {
  ...
}
```

Of course, you'd have to replace these hard coded strings with the data you parsed, but once you saved it this way, it's easy to access the data, because you just have to use `options.get(index)`, while index stands for the index of the current digit of your product number.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I will start researching Map and see how I can implement that into my project. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. I think I mentioned every usage of Map you need, but you should care about creating the object ConfigurationOption with getters and setters and how to parse the file.

Comment: What you gave me is great. I was just looking for a topic to research that may help steer me in the right direction. As the person above noted I really need to do some trial and error with this, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't trying something way out of left field.